# SOA x Microserviços

Tags: microsserviços, soa

Estou habituado a trabalhar com o conceito de [Arquitetura Orientada a Serviços - SOA](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture), estive lendo sobre o assunto e me deparei com o conceito de Arquitetura Orientada a Microserviços, qual seria a(s) diferença(s) entre essas arquiteturas tirando o fato dos serviços serem implementados individualmente?

Comment: Os serviços são sempre implementados individualmente no SOA, essa é a principal vantagem dessa arquitetura na verdade. Microservice é relativamente novo. 
"O termo 'Arquitetura de Microsserviços (Microservice Architecture)' surgiu nos últimos anos para descrever uma maneira específica de desenvolver software como suites de serviços com deploy independente."

(tradução livre de https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html)

Answer (score 1):

Segundo Sam Newman (Autor de alguns livros sobre o assunto) a diferença entre ambos encontra-se no protocolo de comunicação, na implementação, flexibilidade para mudança de tecnologias, evolução independente de cada parte do software, facilidade na implantação, modelagem voltada para contextos específicos do negócio.

Dado que algumas das características citadas são também vantagens da arquitetura orientada a microsserviços.

Enquanto que o SOA, de forma geral é um estilo de arquitetura que tem um foco corporativo maior e mais voltado a integrações.

Resumindo: A diferença entre SOA e Microsserviços é basicamente o escopo.

SOA é mais voltado para o escopo corporativo, enquanto que microsserviços é mais voltado para as aplicações.

Answer (score -1):

Na minha opinião Micro serviços é o SOA sem aquelas complexabilidades na camada de integração é apenas o entregador da mensagem, ou seja é fazer o que deveria ser feito a anos no SOA, porém agora em micro serviços.