# SOA é a mesma coisa que REST?

Tags: terminologia, rest, arquitetura-de-software, soa

Estou aprendendo a respeito de SOA num curso da faculdade. E pelo que eu entendi, SOA esta vinculado com o conceito de Web Services. Existe também as APIs REST que também estão relacionadas com este conceito.

Ambos os termos me geram algumas dúvidas.

## Dúvidas

1. SOA é a mesma coisa que REST?
2. Quando se fala em **serviços** em comparação com SOA, que tipo de **serviços** estão se referindo?
3. E o que é este **serviço**?

Comment: Tenho uma pergunta em aberto, relacionado ao assunto, a quem interessar: [SOA x Microserviços](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214989/soa-x-microservi%C3%A7os)

Comment: Não sei se entendi bem a parte "Quando se fala em serviços em comparação com SOA, que tipo de serviços estão se referindo?" Os serviços em comparação com SOA? não é possível comparar serviços com SOA. Seria comparar a arquitetura da casa com o tijolo na mesma analogia.

Comment: @LeonanCarvalho eu não sei o que é esses **serviços** não consigo visualizar eles.

Comment: Arquitetura é toda orientada a serviços, mas o que é esses serviços?

Comment: @gato Tentei explicar bem o que é o serviço em minha resposta. Desculpe se ficou longa.. eu ainda tentei resumir rs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Se considerarmos que [REST](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45783/101) é uma forma de atender os requisitos de [*web services*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90315/101) e que este por sua vez é uma forma de [SOA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) (service-oriented architecture), então apesar de não ser a mesma coisa, mas todo REST está fazendo um SOA, há uma relação hierárquica entre os termos.

O SOA é uma arquitetura. O Web Service é uma forma de implementar essa arquitetura e o REST é um mecanismo específico dela. Não há nada de oposto neles. Se fizer um REST corretamente sempre estará aplicando SOA.

Até onde sei não tem uma definição formal do que seja um serviço. É algo que faz um trabalho, atende uma demanda, responde com algo que seja relevante para um cenário. Pelo que entendo é algo normalmente mais isolado, provavelmente remoto e que pode ser consumido por diversos consumidores, provavelmente usando tecnologias diferentes, bastando saber como se comunicar com ele.

Pelo menos a Wikipedia diz mais ou menos isso para SOA especificamente, o que obviamente os serviços derivados devem seguir:

- representa logicamente uma atividade de negócio com algum resultado.
- é autocontido
- é uma caixa-preta para os consumidores
- pode ter outros serviços por trás dele

Há um [artigo na Wikipedia que diz o que é um serviço](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_(systems_architecture)), mas achei meio fraco e específico. Talvez não tenha nada melhor. Pelo menos é desse tipo de serviço que estamos falando aqui.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Existe sim definição formal para serviço, em diversas literaturas acadêmicas sobre SOA, uma delas é: ["Um serviço é uma unidade de lógica de solução à qual a orientação do serviço foi aplicada de forma significativa.  (...) Cada serviço recebe seu próprio contexto funcional distinto e é composto por um conjunto de recursos relacionados a esse contexto. Portanto, um serviço pode ser considerado um recipiente de recursos associados a um propósito comum (ou contexto funcional)."](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/223759/7130)

Answer (score 4):

Se entendi bem, o objetivo do autor desta pergunta é relacionar o serviço com o mundo real, criando uma versão metafórica sobre como explicar um serviço. Para uma definição técnica sobre o que é um serviço sugiro acessar esse artigo em português: [SOA - O que é um serviço?](http://blog.iprocess.com.br/2012/10/soa-o-que-e-um-servico/), possui exemplos e diagramas  que podem satisfazer nossões mais acadêmicas sobre o assunto. Se o link anterior estiver offline eu fiz um backup e adicionei ao meu drive podendo ser acessado [aqui](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwn5EqoL5_PYMFp3aXl1UDM2R2M) .

**"SOA é a mesma coisa que REST?"**

Tanto SOA como REST são decisões arquitetônicas sobre como organizar seu projeto de software cliente / servidor. Mais do que isso, são decisões opostas: escolher um significa que você está escolhendo não usar o outro. SOA (Service Oriented Architecture) concentra-se no serviço entregue, sobre como os dados são tratados, enquanto o REST está preocupado com os dados que estão sendo tratados.

Está claro que a arquitetura orientada a serviços(SOA) está orientada nos serviços, e uma arquitetura orientada a recursos(REST) é orientada para recursos. As diferenças entre A e B são muitas vezes melhor explicadas pela definição da essência de A e B, então se resume à questão, o que é um "serviço" e o que é um "recurso"?

Embora pareça bem claro, não é tão fácil distinguir os serviços e recursos, muitas vezes podem ser confundidos ou até mesmo interpretados de forma ambígua . 
Procurando um exemplo mais claro, eu encontrei no SO internacional em uma questão parecida o exemplo:

> o Flickr é um serviço que fornece fotos, mas também pode ser visto como um recurso para fotos. Mas, basicamente, um recurso é mais dados estáticos (como uma foto) e um serviço é mais processamento (por exemplo, entregar uma foto ou redimensionar uma foto para que elas possam mostrar uma miniatura de uma foto).

Muiltas vezes o recurso é confundido com documento ou dado estático, é capaz de você encontrar na internet falando que um recurso é um XML ou um JSON, mas não somente isto, o recurso é um objeto com um tipo, dados associados, relacionamentos com outros recursos e um conjunto de métodos que fazem operações sobre ele. Ele é similar a uma instância de objetos em linguagens de programação Orientada à objetos, com a importante diferença de que apenas alguns métodos padronizados são definidos para um recurso - correspondendo com os padrões do protocolo HTTP: GET(lista), POST(cria), PUT(atualiza) e DELETE(remove) - enquanto uma instância de objeto pode ter diversos métodos sem um padrão fixo. Sendo assim XML ou JSON são apenas formas de representar esse recurso.

Por exemplo, os dados de uma pessoa, pode representar o recurso "Pessoa", com atributos nome, idade, com um recurso relacionado de "Endereço" com seus atributos específicos e por aí vai.

A grosso modo, esse é o resumo do que é um recuso na arquitetura REST, o sistema será construido ao redor destes recursos conhecidos, já que seus métodos já são conhecidos e padronizados.

Conhecendo o que é REST (B), podemos finalmente separar o que é SOA (A) e focar na pergunta,

**"Quando se fala em serviços em comparação com SOA, [...]?"**

Quando vamos para o SOA, a base arquitetônica são os serviços, ou seja as funcionalidades que podem processar e/ou entregar dados dado uma lógica interna, esses serviços vão ditar a forma como o projeto de software será construído, afetando toda a modelagem da aplicação e futuramente na manutenção do software. Para falar sobre os tipos de serviço primeiro definir

**"O que é este serviço?"**

Buscando uma definição mais acadêmica é possível obter a seguinte definição dos livros de engenharia de software:

> Um serviço é uma unidade de lógica de solução à qual a orientação do serviço foi aplicada de forma significativa. É a aplicação de princípios de design de orientação ao serviço que distinguem uma unidade de lógica como um serviço em comparação com unidades de lógica que podem existir apenas como objetos ou componentes. (...)
>   Cada serviço recebe seu próprio contexto funcional distinto e é composto por um conjunto de recursos relacionados a esse contexto. Portanto, um serviço pode ser considerado um recipiente de recursos associados a um propósito comum (ou contexto funcional).

*(tradução do autor), Fonte: http://serviceorientation.com/soaglossary/service*

De acordo com o padrão  proposto pela [Opengroup](http://www.opengroup.org/standards/soa) (entidade que tem como objetivo estabelecer padrões e políticas, e compartilhar as melhores práticas.), um serviço tem quatro propriedades :

- Ele representa logicamente uma atividade comercial com um resultado específico.
- É autônomo.
- É uma caixa preta para seus consumidores.(Seus consumidores não conhecem a lógica interna)
- Pode consistir em outros serviços subjacentes (sub-serviços).

Diferentes serviços podem ser usados em conjunto para fornecer a funcionalidade de uma grande aplicação de software. Até agora, a definição poderia ser uma definição de [programação modular](http://www.dei.isep.ipp.pt/~jcoelho/doc/mod.html) na década de 1970. A arquitetura orientada a serviços(SOA) é menos sobre como modularizar um aplicativo e mais sobre como compor um aplicativo pela integração de componentes de software distribuídos, mantidos separadamente e implantados. É habilitado por tecnologias e padrões que tornam mais fácil a componente se comunicar e cooperar através de uma rede, especialmente uma rede IP.

Eu entendo melhor a diferença ao analisar a forma como um software implementa sua "funcionalidade":

Uma aplicação criada com uma arquitetura de Orientação de Serviço(SOA) combina ou compõe sua funcionalidade de saída baseada em funcionalidades que estão nos serviços que usa "atrás das telas". Por exemplo. O processamento básico consiste em chamar serviços externos, fornecer parâmetros e combinar os resultados para o usuário. É muito comum o Padrão '[Façade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A7ade)' do inglês [Facade Patern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)  (os diagramas no artigo em inglês estão mais claros) para a construção de aplicações SOA.

**"[...] que tipo de serviços estão se referindo?"**

Os serviços ainda podem ser agrupados em 2 categorias:

- Business Services : "Serviços empresariais" ou "Serviços de Negócio" são serviços que executam funções comerciais específicas e são necessários para a conclusão bem-sucedida de um processo comercial. Eles também podem ser chamados de Serviços de Aplicação, pois eles são usados para desenvolver serviços compostos e aplicativos de negócios que automatizam os processos de negócios. Por exemplo, uma empresa de varejo pode ter um "Serviço de Inventário/Estoque", "Serviço de Gerenciamento de Clientes" e "Serviço de Envio de remessas" em seu repositório de serviços empresariais, cada um deles com suas regras de negócio distintas e podendo ainda se comunicar entre sí ou ser sub-serviço de outro serviço maior.
- Infrastructure Services : Podendo ser encontrado na literatura acadêmica como "Serviços Estruturas" ou "Serviços de infra-estrutura", fazem parte de um componente de infraestrutura de gerenciamento central, como um Enterprise Service Bus ([ESB](https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/esb/enterprise-application-integration-eai-and-esb) *link em inglês*). Os Serviços de infra-estrutura fornecem a funcionalidade técnica necessária para a implementação de regras de negócios na SOA, mas não adicionam diretamente valor comercial. Exemplos de serviços de infraestrutura incluem Serviços de Integração , Serviços de Autenticação, Serviços de log de eventos.

Embora existam várias abordagens para categorizar os diferentes tipos de serviços na SOA, a principal distinção a lembrar é a de Serviços de Negócio e Serviços de Infra-estrutura. Os serviços de infra-estrutura são agnósticos e possuem maiores possibilidades de reutilização, enquanto os Serviços empresariais se traduzem diretamente em regras de negócios. As possibilidades de reutilização dos Serviços de Negócios variam de acordo com a forma como são projetadas.